# How to know when a Realm query (RLMResults) operation is completed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence, realm

I am using Realm to handle persisting data to disk in my app.

To return my objects saved in Realm, I use `RLMResults` which successfully returns objects saved in my database

```
RLMResults <Cat *> *cats = [Cat allObjectsInRealm:myRealm];
```

The problem is I have no way of knowing when this operation is completed. I need my network request to wait on the completion of this query before proceeding. The realm documentation is not very thorough and I can't see a way for me to know when this read operation is complete.

Is there some sort of completion block available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm's query APIs are synchronous, and the results they return are available to calling code immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you have a question about how Realm works in a specific situation, I'd suggest asking a new question of your own and providing sufficient detail so someone can provide a detailed answer for you.

Comment: I’m not sure how to state it more plainly than that.